# How can I save a pyspark dataframe in databricks to SAP Hana (SAP Data Warehouse Cloud) using hdbcli?

Tags: sql, pyspark, databricks, hana

I need to push some data from Databricks on AWS to SAP Data Warehouse cloud, and have been encouraged to use the python hdbcli (https://pypi.org/project/hdbcli/). The only documentation I have been able to find is the one in pypi, which is quite scarce. I can see an example of how to push individual rows to a sql table, but I have found no examples of how to save a pyspark dataframe to a table in SAP Data Warehouse cloud.

Documentation examples:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO T1 (ID, C2) VALUES (:id, :c2)'
cursor = conn.cursor()
id = 3
c2 = "goodbye"
cursor.execute(sql, {"id": id, "c2": c2})
# returns True
cursor.close()
```

I have tried the following in my data bricks notebook:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("final_result_local")
sql = "INSERT INTO final_result SELECT * FROM final_result_local"
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.close()
```

After this I got the following error:

> invalid table name:  Could not find table/view FINAL_RESULT_LOCAL in
> schema DATABRICKS_SCHEMA

It seems df.createOrReplaceTempView created the sql table in a different context to the one called by hdbcli, and I don't know how to push the local table to sap data warehouse cloud. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the [Python machine learning client for SAP HANA](https://pypi.org/project/hana-ml/) (`hana-ml`). You can think of it as being an abstraction layer on top of `hdbcli`. The central object to send and retrieve data is the [HANA dataframe](https://help.sap.com/doc/1d0ebfe5e8dd44d09606814d83308d4b/2.0.06/en-US/hana_ml.dataframe.html), which behaves similar to a Pandas dataframe, but is persisted on database side (i.e. this can be a table).

For your scenario, you should be able to create a HANA dataframe and thus a table using function `create_dataframe_from_spark()` (see [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/1d0ebfe5e8dd44d09606814d83308d4b/2.0.06/en-US/hana_ml.dataframe.html)).

Regarding the direct use of `hdbcli`, you can find the full documentation [here](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_CLIENT/f1b440ded6144a54ada97ff95dac7adf/f3b8fabf34324302b123297cdbe710f0.html?locale=en-US) (also linked on PyPi).

Comment: thanks a lot, I've managed to save a pyspark dataframe to SAP HANA, but I can't figure out how to turn turn a hana ml dataframe into a pyspark dataframe. I haven't found anything regarding this in the documentation. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: The Spark functionality is pretty new. I am assuming, you need to call `collect()` on the HANA DF to retrieve a Pandas DF and then take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with using `hdbcli`. Instead look into connecting from Spark directly, this [instruction](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/09/09/calling-hana-views-from-apache-spark/) should be helpful.